# What work is needed to close a block from 2013

Tags: synchronization

Please could you tell me what work is needed to close a block?,also is it possible to to do this while not fully synced?could you also tell me what information would you have to have access the initial coinbase reward in a block

Comment: What is "closing" a block?

Comment: Was this development done on the testnet? If the network protocol port was 18333 (instead of 8333) then it was the testnet.

Comment: sorry Pieter i think it was definatly wrong word lol, proof or work needed to get block reward ,also was not testnet, it was main, basicly i am trying to find the information for the mining,and rewarded coins for being involved in a few ideas and different suggestions back in the days just before and after the realease of bitcoin, also was asked to keep my computer running when possible to help build bitcoin from its core, i was intrested in the idea of digital money, so to get a email from a select list i was over the moon, so done what was asked of as it was all based on being anonymous and